# Is there a way to monitor computer memory for a file to be loaded and then execute a different process to act on the file?

Tags: linux, memory, hash, process, disk

System: Linux (Debian)

I would like to hash many large files (1 GB each, ~2 TB total) on my hard drive. However I do not want to spin my entire hard drive just to generate the hashes. Is there any way I can set up a process that will monitor my system memory for the appearance of an unhashed file to be loaded into memory (by other processes for unrelated purposes), and then execute the hashing algorithm while the file is already loaded in memory?

I just want to prevent redundant disk reads.

Comment: You can use `inotify` to wait for new files to be created or existing files to be updated. Then it can check if there's a hash for the file, and create one if necessary.

Comment: It doesn't work in memory, it detects when the file has been created on the filesystem.